# How to exclude the last part of a variable string using regex

Tags: regex, url

I am currently making a bunch of landing pages that use similar URL structure, but each URL varies in number of words.

So it's something like:

```
http://landingpage.xyz/page-number-five
http://landingpage.xyz/page-number-fifty-four
http://landingpage.xyz/page-for-a-different-topic
```

and for the sent page I just postfix `-sent` like this. The reason I am not adding it as `/sent` is because the platform I am using handles URLs this way.

```
http://landingpage.xyz/page-number-five-sent
http://landingpage.xyz/page-number-fifty-four-sent
http://landingpage.xyz/page-for-a-different-topic-sent
```

Now I found it easy to make a regular expression that identifies all the sent pages which is let's say:

```
\/([a-z0-9\-]*)-sent
```

The thing is that I am not sure how to identify the ones that are not sent. I tried using a similar regular expression using something like this, but it's not working as expected:

```
\/([a-z0-9\-]*)(?!-sent)
```

What's the best way to design the regex for this? Or I am approaching it in the wrong way?

Comment: I managed doing it with specific cases using the negative lookahead like this, but I can't manage to make a generic one. `(page-number-five|page-number-fifty-four)(?!-sent)`.

Comment: Anchor to the end of the string: `\/([a-z0-9\-]*)(?<!-sent)$`

Comment: What is your language / tool?

Comment: @CAustin I tried and tested it on regex101.com, I put a bunch of URLs and for some reason it only detects the last one. It should detect all of them.

Comment: @revo It's not language-specific, I want to use it for Google Analytics objectives.

Comment: It's something specific. I'm not sure about GA but if lookaheads work you may be looking for an approach like `\/(?!.*-sent\b)([a-z0-9\-]*)`

Comment: Enable multiline mode https://regex101.com/r/2vMSAP/1

Comment: @revo please post it as an answer, it worked exactly as needed :)

Comment: @CAustin it is enabled, but it doesn't work the way you put it. revo's version did the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lookahead should be considered where there are some characters left to match. So one at the end of regex doesn't look for anything. As long as I'm not sure whether or not your environment supports lookbehinds, this should be a workaround:

```
\/(?!.*-sent\b)([a-z0-9\-]*)
```